# Sync client slows down computer, what options are available when sites have large number of files

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync

The nature of our office is that we have thousands of small csv files per site (10,000 -> 100,000) in folder like structures.  When users add multiple sites, it seems that SharePoint sync just doesn't want to work well.  Many have trouble keeping up, from 3rd Gen i5 to 8th gen i5s, all with 8gb of ram.

Is there any best practices that will allow users to have a better experience?  currently we have them unlink sites they are not using and add the ones they need, But with dozens of sites - this is time consuming.  The operation on the files cannot be done through the online interface unfortunately.

The users do not require may files to be synced at all, maybe 10's of files.  But it just takes so long to add sites and remove them.

Is there any suggestions on handling sites synced with many files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 and Mac supports "[files on demand](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/save-disk-space-with-onedrive-files-on-demand-for-windows-10-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e)", which allows you to sync metadata about the files, but not the files themselves until a user accesses the file. Great feature, and it certainly addresses performance and disk space issues.

Comment: Thanks @Mike2500, we are using Files on Demand.  It seems that sometimes it will go through and "Update" all files even though they are still set to "On Demand" and are just the meta data.